# Median of two sorted arrays

Tags: algorithms, divide-and-conquer, binary-search

Two sorted arrays `A` and `B` are given having size `l` and `m` respectively. Our task is to find the median of these two sorted arrays combined. Suppose the length of the combined array is `n` i.e. `n = l + m`.By definition the median will be greater than half of the  elements  and less than the other half.

Suppose `A[i]` is the median. Then since A is sorted so

```
                            A[i] >= A[k] for all k = 0 to i - 1
```

and it will also be greater than **`j = ⌈n/2⌉- (i - 1)`** elements in `B` as `i + j` must be  equal to `⌈n/2⌉`.

```
                      A[i] >= B[k] for all k = 0 to ⌈n/2⌉- (i - 1)
```

If `A[i]` is not the median, then depending on whether `A[i]` is greater
or less than `B[j]` and `B[j + 1]`, you know that `A[i]` is either greater than or less than the median.

Thus binary search for A[i] can be done here. Following is the pseudo code I have found from a [website](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/f1fea97937edc97ae96691b80651421a_ps9sol.pdf):

```
                MEDIAN-SEARCH(A[1 . . l], B[1 . . m], left,right)

                 if left > right:
                   MEDIAN-SEARCH(B, A, max(1, ⌈n/2⌉ − l), min(m, ⌈n/2⌉))

                 i = ⌊(left + right)/2⌋

                 j = ⌈n/2⌉ - i

                 if (j = 0 or A[i] > B[j]) and (j = m or A[i] <= B[j + 1])
                   return A[i]

                 else if (j = 0 or A[i] > B[j]) and j != m and A[i] > B[j + 1]
                   return MEDIAN-SEARCH(A, B, left, i − 1)

                 else
                   return MEDIAN-SEARCH(A, B, i + 1, right)
```

The initial call to find median will be

```
                 MEDIAN-SEARCH(A[1..l], B[1..m], max(1, ⌈n/2⌉ − m), min(l, ⌈n/2⌉))
```

My question here is:

1. I am not able to visualize intuitively how **`left`** and **`right`** initial values are being used in the code above.
2. What will be time complexity of the algorithm? Will it be `log O(N)`? or will it be `log O(max(l, m))`?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/69863/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/85410/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/159488/755

Comment: Initial values left and right are: 
`left = max(1, ⌈n/2⌉ − m)`
`right = min(l, ⌈n/2⌉)`

I am not able to visualize the rationale behind that. Can Anyone help me understand that? I saw one answer regarding same algorithm by @YuvalFilmus [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/95715/166135) but there also it is not explained.

Answer (score 0):

The source hinted that it is by the definition of median and outlined how to verify an element in $O(1)$.

If $l > m$, $left = \lceil (l - m) / 2 \rceil$, $right = \lceil (l + m) / 2 \rceil$. Else, $left = 1$, $right = l$.

The median is guaranteed to be found in $A[left..right]$ using that range, or if not then trivially found in $B$.

As this is essentially a binary search, it runs in $O(log(min(l, m))$.

If $A$ and $B$ are not sorted, you can combine both and run quickselect in $O(log(max(l, m))$ instead.